# Turn off Tooltip of WPF Toolkit chart control

Tags: wpf, charts, tooltip, wpftoolkit

I am using the WPF ToolKit `ChartControl` to create a columneries  chart. Whenever I move mouse to my `Chart`, the `ToolTip` value will be displayed. I dont need this `ToolTip`, So how can I turn this off?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this control so I can't say for sure but in general you can disable tooltips by setting the attached property `ToolTipService.IsEnabled` to false like this:

```
<TextBlock ToolTip="World" ToolTipService.IsEnabled="False">Hello</TextBlock>
```